# Why does Java allow an interface to extend another interface both directly and indirectly?

Tags: interface

Java allows the following code to compile.  Excuse the naming.  I would have chosen better names if I knew why one would write this code, but that is the whole reason for my question.  Note that IFace3 extends IFace1 both directly and indirectly (through IFace2).  Is there a practical use for this capability?

```
public interface IFace1 {
    public void meth1();
}

interface IFace2 extends IFace1 {
    public void meth2();
}

interface IFace3 extends IFace1, IFace2 {
     public void meth3();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The situation where multiple inheritance causes problems is when a member is defined different ways on different inheritance paths.  At least in the days before Java allowed default interface implementations in the middle of a hierarchy, it wasn't possible for part of an interface to be defined in conflicting ways on different inheritance paths, since the actual implementation of every interface member would need to be contained in the class that implements it.  Even if an interface includes `Interface1.Method1` both directly and by extension through `Interface2`, the same method in an implementing class will be used to satisfy the members of both interfaces.

Comment: With all do respect, does that mean "no"?  I am relatively new to java and not familiar with default interfaces.  Do I need to learn about them in order to understand the answer to my questions?

Comment: @Andre: If forbidding something would occasionally cause trouble, allowing it wouldn't, and allowing it is no harder than forbidding it, those would together imply that the action may as well be allowed.